# How does this resolver extension function work?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I need help interpreting a piece of code.

I have been attempting to learn how to authenticate users with jwt and returning tokens and refresh tokens.

It has been a fun ride and I came across this  [repository](https://github.com/benawad/graphql-express-template/tree/22_advanced_jwt_auth) where the user added an extension/chain function which as far as I understand combines multiple graphql resolvers:

```
// I don't understand this function
const createResolver = (resolver) => {
  const baseResolver = resolver;
  baseResolver.createResolver = (childResolver) => {
    const newResolver = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      await resolver(parent, args, context, info);
      return childResolver(parent, args, context, info);
    };
    return createResolver(newResolver);
  };
  return baseResolver;
};

export const requiresAuth = createResolver((parent, args, context) => {
  if (!context.user || !context.user.id) {
    throw new Error('Not authenticated');
  }
});

export const requiresAdmin = requiresAuth.createResolver((parent, args, context) => {
  if (!context.user.isAdmin) {
    throw new Error('Requires admin access');
  }
});
```

it is used like this:

```
Query: { 
    getBook: requiresAuth.createResolver((parent, args, { models }, info) =>
       // do something fun
    ),
}
```

I don't understand the createResolver function and I am asking if this is some type of programming paradigm where there are articles that I can read and understand it better.

Googling I did find `graphql-resolvers` which as far as I understand does the same thing but in this case, I would need to install yet another package which I would like to avoid but at the same time, I don't want to use a function that I don't fully understand.

Edit:

What I understand of the function/think I understand:

chains multiple functions together by calling one function and then inside of that function passing in a new function: `requiresAuth.createResolver`
Inside of the function itself I'm having trouble figuring it out. 
We get a new variable `baseResolver` which we chain a new `createResolver`
where we then recursively call the parent function.

I can't understand the flow of this I guess.

Comment: well, I'm not familiar with graphQL, but the code simply adds a `function` to another `function`

Comment: @appleapple Ive never seen syntax like this before. Is there a name for this?

Comment: Looks like recursion because `createResolver` calls itself.

Comment: @CodingLittle I'm not sure there is a name, but basically you can add anything to a function just like normal object in javascript (example `{function X(){};X.a=1;console.log(X.a);}`

Comment: or `{function X(){};X.a=()=>1;console.log(X.a());}`

Comment: @CodingLittle maybe you can clarify what you don't understand about the provided source code. Just saying you don't understand it makes this question very broad.

Comment: OK, I read the code a little more and it look like just chain the functions...

Comment: @DanielRearden you are right, please view edits. It is broad in the sence since I dont fully understand whats going on in the function. I undersatnd the end result but why it has to be written the way it is confuses me.

Comment: @CodingLittle well, the `baseResolver` doesn't do anything since `resolver` is never changed.

Comment: The comments section is getting a bit large. For the person who understands it, could i get an answer where it is breaken down or written in a easier way? im reading through the higher-order-functions link at the moment but it still doesn't give me a fully clear picture of what the function is doing.

Comment: it just 'decorates' your original resolver by calling auth resolver first and invokes original resolver only if user is authed ... it saves you from manually modyfing all resolvers needing auth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of renaming some things, because the existing names are very confusing.

```js
const augment = (resolver) => {
  resolver.add = (nextResolver) => {
    const wrapper = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      await resolver(parent, args, context, info)
      return nextResolver(parent, args, context, info)
    }
    return augment(wrapper)
  }
  return resolver
}
```

At every step of the way an `.add` method is added to the returned function, to enable chaining like so:

```
augment(resolver1).add(resolver2).add(resolver3)...
```

Every time `.add` is called, a new async lambda function (`wrapper`) is created. `wrapper` closes over both `resolver` and `nextResolver`. When it is eventually run, `wrapper` will call `resolver`, wait for the result, and then call `nextResolver`, and return the result.

`wrapper` is then passed to `augment` to add an `.add` function to it (to enable chaining). This new `add` function closes over the argument supplied to `augment` (which is `wrapper`). The augmented `wrapper` function is returned.

So, when `.add` is subsequently called, the `resolver` argument is the `wrapper` function of the call to `.add` on the previous resolver. So:

```
await resolver(parent, args, context, info)
return nextResolver(parent, args, context, info)
```

...will await the previously created `wrapper` function, and then invoke the latest `nextResolver`.

In this way, successive calls to `.add` construct a chain of async functions.

And when you want to run the chain, you can simply invoke the returned function, ignoring the `.add` property on it.

Note that each resolver is passed same arguments, to avoid the user having to worry about passing them on down the chain.

The function can be re-written as:

```js
const augment = (resolver) => {
  resolver.add = (nextResolver) => 
    augment((...args) => 
      resolver(...args)
        .then(() => nextResolver(...args)))
  return resolver
}
```

...or:

```js
const inSequence = (resolvers) => 
    (...args) => 
        resolvers.reduce((acc, el) => 
            acc.then(() => el(...args)), Promise.resolve())

const getBook = inSequence([auth, admin, getBookResolver])
const query = { getBook }
```

...or:

```js
const inSequence = (resolvers) => 
    async (...args) => {
        for(let el of resolvers) {
            await el(...args)
        }
    }
const getBook = inSequence([auth, admin, getBookResolver])
const query = { getBook }
```

Comment: Dont take this the wrong way but I could hug you right now. This made it alot easier to understand, thank you!

Comment: I hope im not asking to much but do you perhaps have an article or some kind of documentation that so that I can read more about this. Thanks again!

Comment: This website expands on some functional programming concepts that might help you: https://dev.to/damxipo/functional-programming-in-javascript-442p

Answer (score 1):

```
const createResolver = (resolver) => {
  const baseResolver = resolver;
  baseResolver.createResolver = (childResolver) => {
    const newResolver = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      await resolver(parent, args, context, info);
      return childResolver(parent, args, context, info);
    };
    return createResolver(newResolver);
  };
  return baseResolver;
};

export const requiresAuth = createResolver( /*resolver_A*/ (parent, args, context) => {
  if (!context.user || !context.user.id) {
    throw new Error('Not authenticated');
  }
});
```

`requiresAuth` returned by `createResolver` is a function (passed as parameter, marked with `resolver_A`) decorated with additional function inside ... available by `.createResolver()`

```
export const requiresAdmin = requiresAuth.createResolver( /*resolver_B*/ (parent, args, context) => {
  if (!context.user.isAdmin) {
    throw new Error('Requires admin access');
  }
});
```

`requiresAuth.createResolver(` invoked with another resolver passed as parameter (`resolver_B` is `childResolver`) creates and returns new async resolver `newResolver`. `newResolver` when called `await`s for results of `resolver` (`resolver_A` in this case) and then calls currently passed resolver (`resolver_B`).

`createResolver(newResolver);` not only return chained async resolver - function again ('reccurency') is decorated with `.createResolver` allowing to chain resolvers. You can again use `.createResolver()`:

```
Query: { 
  editBook: requiresAdmin.createResolver((parent, args, { models }, info) =>
```

`editBook` will sequentially check auth (`if (!context.user || !context.user.id) ...`) and rights (`if (!context.user.isAdmin) ...`) before running target resolver.

It's equal to

```
editBook: createResolver(authResolverFn).createResolver(adminResolverFn).createResolver(editBookResolverFn)
```

... but only first `createResolver` is a name of 'external' function.

Comment: I think that changing the names like @52d6c6af did made it a bit easier for me to follow. 
In any case your explenation still makes my life easier. Also thank you for suggesting jwt tokens in my other question, it guided me to this.